# "Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object." while coding a Drag&Drop using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm programming a drag n drop tool with HTML and JavaScript, but I'm encountering an issue. When I try to drop the cell I started dragging, I get the folowing error: "TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object."

Here is the HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
</head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="./css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>
      <ul id="menu">
        <li><a>Maquette <br />du cursus</a></li>
        <li><a>Séquences thématiques</a></li>
        <li><a>Cours</a></li>
      </ul>
    </h1>
  </header>

  <div class="heading">
    <h1 class="title">Maquette du nouveau cursus</h1>
  </div>

<div class="containermenu">
  <div id="scrollbar" id="style-1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <div class="cell" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
    <div class="cello" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="model-container">
  <div class="grid-container" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondrop="drop(event)">
    <div class="grid-row">
      <div class="grid-cell" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>
      <div class="grid-cell" ></div>
      <div class="grid-cell"></div>
      <div class="grid-cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row">
      <div class="grid-cell"></div>
      <div class="grid-cell"></div>
      <div class="grid-cell"></div>
      <div class="grid-cell"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-row">
      <div class="grid-cell"></div>
      <div class="grid-cell"></div>
      <div class="grid-cell"></div>
      <div class="grid-cell"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p></p>
</div>

<footer>
  <p>Footer</p>
</footer>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS code :

```
@import url(fonts/clear-sans.css);
[draggable=true]

html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  color: #726880;
  font-family: "Clear Sans", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px; }

body {
  margin: 0px 0; }

header {
  padding : 10px 0;
  background : #726880;
  text-align : center;
  font-weight : bold;
}

ul#menu
{
  height: 50px ;
  font-size:0.8em;
  margin: 0 ;
  list-style-type: none ;
  text-align: center;
}

ul#menu li
{
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  padding: 1px;
}

ul#menu li a
{
  width: 255px ;
  line-height: 25px ;
  display: inline-block ;
  text-align:center;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

footer {
  font-weight : bold;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background : #726880;
  text-align : center;
  padding : 10px;
}

.heading:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both; }

h1.title {
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align : center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  line-height: 1.65; }

a {
  color: #776e65;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer; }

hr {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d4d0;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px; }

.container {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 ; }

.containermenu {
  cursor: default;
  background: #726880;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 264px;
  height: 425px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left;
  margin-left: 80px;
}

#scrollbar
{
  cursor: default;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 224px;
  height: 340px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 60px;
    margin-left: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.model-container {
  padding: 15px;
  margin-left: 400px;
  cursor: default;
  background: #726880;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 800px;
  height: 425px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid-container-menu {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1; }

.grid-container {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1; }

.grid-row {
  margin-bottom: 15px; }
  .grid-row:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 15px; }
  .grid-row:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both; }

.grid-cell {
  width: 181.25px;
  height: 106.25px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #FFF8DC; }
  .grid-cell:last-child {
    margin-right: 0; }

.cell {
  cursor:pointer;
  width: 181.25px;
  height: 106.25px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #841D3B; }
  .cell:last-child {
    margin-right: 0; }
  .cell:focus{
    outline:none;
  }

  .cello {
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 181.25px;
    height: 106.25px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #241A3B; }
    .cell:last-child {
      margin-right: 0; }
    .cell:focus{
      outline:none;
    }
```

And the JavaScript one :

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    console.log(ev);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    console.log(data);
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

Here is the output and the console with JS Bin :

JS Bin on jsbin.com

For the moment, I'm just trying to switch the red cell with the purple one using DnD (so only what's in the "containermenu" div matters for the moment).

I've already done some research, but none of the answers could really help me.

Can someone please explain me how to solve this ?

Thank you.

Comment: what does this line `ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");` returns ? in drop function

Comment: is it always happens to you when you drag or only on certain drag and drop situations?

Comment: I may be wrong, but to me, it retrieves drag data as a DOMString for the specified type, which is text/plain here. I used this because the cell will be containing text when the code will be finished.

Comment: I happens when I'm dropping what I dragged in a drop target.

Answer (score 0):

You should give the draggable elements a `id` property.change.

If you want to give a id of 'cell-1' to the element,you  should change

`<div class="grid-cell" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"></div>`

to

`<div class="grid-cell" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" id="cell-1"></div>`

Comment: Well, now I have a new problem... Somehow, more than one cell can be dropped at the same place, while I want the drop target to be restricted to one cell at a time. Is there any method for that?

Comment: you can use a variable to store the state of whether the drop target contains a cell.if it has one,don't append the cell.

Comment: Excuse me, I couldn't access my computer these few last days. I'll try this. Thanks!